# URL::asset() with php artisan command gives me localhost links

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I try to send some emails with a CLI command with php artisan of Laravel, something easy like :

```
 php artisan invitation:send recipient@mail.com
```

This command is calling a UserController method which contains :

```
Mail::send('emails.beta.invitation', $data, function($message) use ($address)
{
    $message->to($address)
            ->subject('My subject');

});
```

The problem is that when it creates the HTML using the view, all references to `URL::asset('img/foo.png')` in the template gives me a beautiful :

```
http://localhost/img/foo.png
```

instead of the website url :

```
http://mydomain.com/img/foo.png
```

If I call this method by calling it in the web browser, there is the good URI for the asset.
I even tried with an environment to the CLI but it doesn't work. (ie. `--env=production`)

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All right, I got it.

When using the CLI, Laravel is using the config file `app/config/app.php` to read the 'url' (default `'url' => 'http://localhost'`).

So I just had to create a new config file under `app/config/local/app.php` with :

```
<?php
return array(
    'url' => 'http://localhost:8000',
);
```

And to change the `app/config/app.php` with my production value :

```
'url' => 'http://mydomain.com'
```

Now it works well !

Comment: Remember put your answer as accepted if you get the solution by yourself.

Comment: Yes, I have to wait 2 days before accepting it, but I'll do it :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2554#issuecomment-246645265

mstephens commented on 13 Sep 2016
Hello

In App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider you can define the following:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    /** @var \Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator $url */
    $url = $this->app['url'];
    // Force the application URL
    $url->forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));
}
```